# Configuring Separate Broker for Storing Offsets on Kafka Topic in a Kafka Connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-kinesis

As I am newbie to Kafka and Kafka Connector, I have a use case where we are pushing data from Kinesis Stream to Kafka Topic, as this will be a plug and play feature we are using Kafka Connect to serve the use case. In this use case we are storing the offsets on Kafka Topic which will be usually created on broker which we configured but the case here is we have the brokers which are on clients environment and we don't want to give the offset data to the client as in case of any failures if they loose the data then we will not be able to restore the data from last checkpoint.
Do we have any provision or any way in Kafka Connect where we can store offset on a separate topic on its own broker and customer's data topic on customers broker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Kafka Connect can only store offsets on the cluster configured as `boostrap.servers` in its worker properties file.

You could use MirrorMaker to replicate connect-offsets / consumer offsets topic to a separate cluster, but Connect wouldn't know about the other cluster on its own.

Comment: Thanks, we are introducing a backup solution to store the offsets